# how I get version of a program in linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, port

In Windows you can do:

```
CSystemInfo info;
this->m_strVersion = info.GetFileVersion( CFileSystemHelper::GetApplicationPath() + _T("/test.exe") );
```

to get the version number.

How would I do it in C++ on linux ?

Comment: It typically depends on the program. You can try invoking it with only the `--version` option and parse its output, but there is no requirement for a program to expose a version number in Linux. You can also try to interface with the package manager, but there are several of these too.

Comment: What you describe is a "windows thing". It doesn't exist in *nix.

Answer (score 3):

Windows adopts a version resource system with standard API support, Linux and UNIX have no such high level concepts for a variety of reasons ranging from legacy to redundancy.

Best options are to query the local packaging system (RPM, APT, etc), or try executing with `--version` command line parameter which is a [recommended GNU standard](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html).

Example RPM query on command line for the Samba tool `smbget`:

> ```
> # rpm -q -f /usr/bin/smbget --queryformat '%{version}\n'
> 3.0.33
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to retrieve the path of the currently executing executable.

On Linux, you could use the `/proc/` pseudo-file system. Read the [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page for more.

Specifically, you probably want to do something like

```
char myexepath[512];
memset (myexepath, 0, sizeof(myexepath);
readlink ("/proc/self/exe", myexepath, sizeof(myexepath));
```

(but you really should check for runtime errors above)

If you simply wanted to display the version of a program, you should have a convention about it. Usually accepting `--version` as the program first argument.

I invite you to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).